# Activates javascript after 'x' seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible that the javascript automatically activates after 8 seconds when a user is not using the link, so that it continues every 8 seconds, from Q1 to Q2, Q3 etc

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function laatZien(divID) {
 var tabs = ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"];
  for(var i in tabs)
  { if (tabs[i] != divID)
  {            
  document.getElementById(tabs[i]).className = "verstopt"; b
  } }
  var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if(item.className=="verstopt") {
    item.className = "zichtbaar"
    } else {
    item.className = "zichtbaar"
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="Q1" class="zichtbaar">
  <a href="javascript:laatZien('Q2');">Next (Q2)</a>
</div>
<div id="Q2" class="verstopt">
  <a href="javascript:laatZien('Q3');">Next (Q3)</a>
</div>
<div id="Q3" class="verstopt">
  <a href="javascript:laatZien('Q1');">Back</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Q1.verstopt, #Q2.verstopt, #Q3.verstopt{
display: none;
}

#Q1.zichtbaar, #Q2.zichtbaar, #Q3.zichtbaar{
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use the setInterval function provided by javascript and call your method every 8000ms.

```
setInterval(function(){ laatZien(element) }, 8000);
```

> The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

here is a little fiddle for you:

```js
var i = 2;
setInterval(function(){
    $('div').removeClass('is_active');
    $('.q'+i).addClass('is_active');
    if(i == 3) {i = 0;}
    i++;
},8000);
```

```css
.is_active {
    display: block;
}
div {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="q1 is_active">Test 1</div>
<div class="q2">Test 2</div>
<div class="q3">Test 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
var timerId = setInterval(function() {
alert("tick");
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function() {
clearInterval(timerId);
alert('tick');
}, 5000);
```